# How does the corruption sigil in Lichdom:Battlemage work?

Tags: lichdom-battlemage

After receiving ice, fire, and kinesis, all of which I have learned how they work, I chose my fourth sigil, corruption. The only problem is, I have no idea how it works. I tried crafting a few things and then using them, but it seems like there is literally 0 damage being dealt. How does corruption work?

This is for a pre-alpha game called Lichdom: Battlemage, in case anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 3):

It sends out a little swarm of little parasitic organisms that upon contact will start to grow on the target and explode dealing damage. At least thats how the targetted ability works. not sure about The AoE or Block at all. Haven't used it that much due to the damage being like 52-58 on crit so its not that great.

Comment: Thanks. Have you noticed that combinations of other sigils (such as freezing someone with ice, then landing a fire spell) does extra damage?

Answer (score 1):

The ray for corruption is my absolute favorite control/mastery spell early game.

After hitting them with a literal hose of filth (try to keep it on them long enough for a crit), run away. After several seconds you'll see a purple tumor on them. Hit them with a fully charged fire attack (I prefer *Firestrike*) and the tumor will pop off and float next to you. This is the Hive, it's my best friend. It then sends out small parasites to **all** nearby enemies, giving them about a 60% mastery debuff. One charged firestrike takes out all basic units then.

I've been experimenting with others, but each spell or type of spell for corruption does something different.